# Redirect from generic Heroku domain to custom domain

Tags: heroku, web-deployment

I have an old version of a web app which was deployed using Heroku to a generic Heroku domain i.e. https://abcdefg.herokuapp.com/

I have a newer version of this web app deployed separately using Azure at a custom domain i.e. https://www.abcdefg.com/

However many users are still using the old Heroku domain and are going to the old version of the app.

Is there an easy way in the Heroku Dashboard to redirect from the generic Heroku domain to another domain i.e. my custom domain in this case?